# How do Pebble JS watchapp receive message from Android APP

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, pebble-js

I wanna make a wathcapp with Pebble.js but I found that Pebble.js can only send a message. There is no method can I receive a message from my Android APP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand that Pebble.js apps are already running on the phone. You cannot use AppMessage to communicate with an Android app.

You can however use a Web server inside your app and connect to it from the JavaScript (with `ajax()` calls or a WebSocket).

Comment: Thanks. But if pebble.js app running on the phone, how i can get the localStorage data that set on my pebble.js app?\

Comment: Via a websocket or a http request to your Android app.